# Page Argument in Title

Tags: routes

How can I have the page argument appear in the page title?

```
    $items['path/path/%'] = array(
    'title'            => t('Dynamic Title %1'),
    'page callback'    => 'pagecallback',
    'page arguments' => array(2),
     'type'             => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
```

Is there some kind of text replacement or something you can use in there, or is what I'm asking impossible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `title callback` function along with `title arguments`:

```
$items['path/path/%'] = array(
  'title callback' => 'MYMODULE_page_title',
  'title arguments' => array(2),
  'page callback'    => 'pagecallback',
  'page arguments' => array(2),
  'type'             => MENU_CALLBACK,
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
);

function MYMODULE_page_title($arg) {
  return t('Arg is: @arg', array('@arg' => $arg));
}
```

The default `title callback` is [`t()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7), so if you just need the argument to be passed straight through as the title you can get away with just using `title arguments`.

See [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) for more details.

Comment: Perfect thank you, I couldn't find anything like this in the drupal docs but I didn't expect there to be a callback for the title.

Comment: @DanielWaters, If you do not want a callback for title, then you can use `drupal_set_title` function in your `pagecallback` function.